# Wordpress resize image = Big

Tags: image, wordpress

My theme is working Ok. I have no problem in resizing, but there's a big problem in the size of the images generated.

I upload a 30KB image: 300*250

It got resized, the 100*80 image is 20Kb which is insane. It should be at maximum 5 or 6KB.

I am using the Wordpress build in resize function. Using WP Smush which is not helping that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fully uncompressed jpeg image 80 by 100 px image with 8-bit color can take at maximum:

```
 80 * 100 * (24 bits per pixel) / 8 = 24000 bytes ~= 23.4375 kb
```

Wordpress' default compression ratio is 90% but if that is too high, you can change it using the [WP_Image_Editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) class added in version 3.5.

Specifically, you should use [set_quality](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php#L194) either with wp_editor_set_quality or WP_Image_Editor::set_quality() as suggested in the [Wordpress Filter Reference for jpeg_quality](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

Comment: I used that, is it the same?

add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'jpeg_quality_callback');
function jpeg_quality_callback($arg) {
return (int)80;
}